# False problem from Stewart book

Tags: calculus

During the solution of Stewart book Calculus I ran into the following problem:
Show that $\sin^{-1}(\tanh x)=\tan^{-1}(\sinh x)$

**My solution:** The LHS of identity is equal to $$\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1-(\tanh x)^2}}=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1-\dfrac{(e^x-e^{-x})^2}{(e^x+e^{-x})^2}}}=\dfrac{e^x+e^{-x}}{2}=\cosh x$$
However, the RHS of identity is equal to $$\dfrac{1}{1+(\sinh x)^2}=\dfrac{1}{1+\dfrac{(e^x-e^{-x})^2}{4}}=\dfrac{1}{\cosh^2 x}$$
And we see that they are not the same. Am I right?

Comment: The LHS certainly isn't what you say it is.

Comment: How did you get the left hand side is THAT?

Answer (score 1):

Your derivation is wrong. To prove the claim, set $$y = \sin^{-1}(\tanh(x)) \implies \sin(y) = \tanh(x) \implies \tan(y) = \frac{\tanh(x)}{\sqrt{1-(\tanh(x))^2}}.$$
Simplify and prove the claim.

Comment: Yes you are right. I was totally wrong :(

Answer (score 1):

Instead of computing $\sin^{-1}(\tanh x)$ and $\tan^{-1}(\sinh x)$, what you actually computed was $(\sin^{-1})'(\tanh x)$ and $(\tan^{-1})'(\sinh x)$, since $(\sin^{-1})'(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$ and $(\tan^{-1})'(x) = \frac{1}{1+x^2}$.

You can still salvage a solution from what you did: indeed, by the chain rule we have
$$(\sin^{-1}\circ\tanh)'(x) = (\sin^{-1})'(\tanh x)\cdot (\tanh)'(x) = (\cosh x)\frac{1}{\cosh^2 x} = \frac{1}{\cosh x} $$
while
$$(\tan^{-1}\circ\sinh)'(x) = (\tan^{-1})'(\sinh x)\cdot (\sinh)'(x) = \frac{1}{\cosh^2 x}(\cosh x) = \frac{1}{\cosh x}.$$
Thus $\sin^{-1}\circ\tanh$ and $\tan^{-1}\circ\sinh$ have the same derivatives, so they differ by a constant. Plugging in $x=0$ shows that this constant must be zero.